# How can I make a trainable parameter in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

thanks for looking my question.

For example.

The final output is the sum of two matrix A and B,like this:

```
output = keras.layers.add([A, B])
```

Now,I  want to build a new parameter x to change the output.

**I want to make newoutput = A*x+B*(1-x)**

and x is a **trainable parameter** in my network.

what should I do?
please help me ~ thanks very much!

**edit(part of code ):**

```
conv1 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(input)
drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop1)

conv2 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
conv2 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(conv2)

up1 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop2))

#the line I want to change:
merge = add([drop2,up1])
#this layer is simply add drop2 and up1 layer.now I want to add a trainable parameter x to adjust the weight of thoese two layers.
```

I tried to use the codes,but still occured some questions:

1.how can I use my own layer?

```
merge = Mylayer()(drop2,up1)
```

or otherway?

2.what is the meaning of out_dim?
those parameters are all 3-dim matrix.what is the mening of out_dim?

thank you...T.T

**edit2(solved)**

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import numpy as np

from keras.layers import add

class MyLayer(Layer):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):

    self._x = K.variable(0.5)
    self.trainable_weights = [self._x]

    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

def call(self, x):
    A, B = x
    result = add([self._x*A ,(1-self._x)*B])
    return result

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the secondary edit code block! This finally got me off the ground using TF 1.12 and Keras 2.2.4. This is by far the most confusing API ever...for those who are having issues with this, check that `model.summary()` reports that there is a trainable parameter in the layer. For me, I had to call `add_weight(shape=())` in `build()` to properly add the weight to the model graph. `shape=()` indicates that the weight is scalar, and you can use it to add/mult/divide directly against tensors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a custom class which inherits from `Layer` and create the trainable parameter using `self.add_weight(...)`. You can find an example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145277/creating-a-keras-layer-of-trainable-weights) and [there](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/).

For your example, the layer would somehow look like this:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import numpy as np

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self._A = self.add_weight(name='A', 
                                    shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    trainable=True)
        self._B = self.add_weight(name='B', 
                                    shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return K.dot(x, self._A) + K.dot(1-x, self._B)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

**Edit**: Just based on the names I (wrongly) assumed that `x` is the layers input and you want to optimize `A` and `B`. But, as you stated, you want to optimize `x`. For this, you can do something like this:

```py
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import numpy as np

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self._x = self.add_weight(name='x', 
                                    shape=(1,),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        A, B = x
        return K.dot(self._x, A) + K.dot(1-self._x, B)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]
```

**Edit2**: You can call this layer using

```
merge = Mylayer()([drop2,up1])
```

Comment: I hava a question:for my example,x is the trainable parameter, A/B matrix is input parameter. why don not add x In the build function?

Comment: T.T  sorry sir,I still cant run my code . see my edit please

Comment: @lomo See the changes in my edit. I thought you wanted `x` to be a tensor, but I guess you just want it to be a scalar, right?

Comment: YES,but how can I use the layer in my model?    code: {  merge = Mylayer()(layer1,layer2) } is not work

Comment: the wrong message is :TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: if I use { merge6 = MyLayer()((layer1,layer2))  } the wrong message is :ValueError: Layer my_layer_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'tuple'>. Full input: [(<tf.Tensor 'dropout_1/cond/Merge:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'conv2d_11/Relu:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 512) dtype=float32>)]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Comment: I tried this before,the wrong message is :ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'my_layer_1/random_uniform/RandomUniform' (op: 'RandomUniform') with input shapes: [].

Comment: I am so sad ~the code before we change can work and train .so the problem is not in the codes in other place.

Comment: Hi,In the morning,I finally solved this problem,I will show in my edit!！thanks